# Porque o background-color não aparece?

Tags: css

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte codigo:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("imagens/fundo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.bloco2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 2%;
  width: 2%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.linha1 {
  margin-left: 20%;
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}

.online {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
}

.jack {
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 5%;
  max-width: 20%;
  margin-left: 80%;
  position: absolute;
}

.loginsteam {
  margin-left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.goncalo {
  background-color: green;
  width: 10%;
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jack">
      Best Jackpot: Goncalo
    </div>
    <div class="online">
      <span style="color:#a9a9a9; font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-transform: uppercase;">Online:</span>
      <span style="color:#a9a9a9; font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif; font-size:17px; text-transform: uppercase;"><b>20</b></span>
    </div>

    <div class="goncalo">
      Goncalo
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="imagens/logo.png">
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      Oi
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

No *style* da classe `.goncalo`, o `background-color` não está a aparecer quando eu meto `position absolute`. Porquê? Como posso resolver isto.

Comment: Eu, enganei-me no botão :S queria aceitar, e cliquei no botão errado, se poder adicionar denovo agradecia.

Comment: E a incompatilidade está entre `position: absolute` e `height` relativo. Ao definir a altura em `px`, por exemplo, funciona como esperado. Ainda tentando entender o porquê exatamente.

Comment: Pois já vi que sim, mas também não consigo entender o motivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele não desaparece, o que acontece é que fica sem uma referência para altura quando está em absoluto. Dás 20% de nada em `height:20%`, pois o elemento pai `.container` não tem um altura definida para servir com referência.

Talvez para o que pretendes deves começar por definir uma altura ao `.container`, por exemplo `height:  500px;`
Aqui a opção depende do que pretendes fazer, mas aqui fica uma hipótese para o teus código(altera o teu código):

```
.container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  height:  500px;
}
```

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 3):

A incompatibilidade se dá entre as propriedades `position`, definida como `absolute`, `height`, com valores relativos. Isso acontece porque ao utilizar a propriedade `position: absolute` você estará removendo o elemento do fluxo natural de exibição, sendo ignorado pelos elementos posteriores e ignorando propriedades de seu elemento pai. Possuir uma altura relativa só faria sentido quando o valor é relativo à propriedade do elemento pai, como o elemento com `position: absolute` ignora tais propriedades, não é possível ter valores relativos.

> Essa relação é reestabelecida se o elemento pai possui `position: relative` e definir um valor absoluto para a propriedade que desejas manter como relativa. Neste caso, bastaria adicionar uma altura com valor absoluto à `.container` que seria possível manter a altura de `.goncalo` relativa.

Basta você alterar o valor da propriedade `height` para um valor absoluto, tal como 50 px, como no exemplo abaixo, e verá que funcionará como esperado.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("imagens/fundo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.bloco2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 2%;
  width: 2%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.linha1 {
  margin-left: 20%;
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}

.online {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
}

.jack {
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 5%;
  max-width: 20%;
  margin-left: 80%;
  position: absolute;
}

.loginsteam {
  margin-left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.goncalo {
  background-color: green;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jack">
      Best Jackpot: Goncalo
    </div>
    <div class="online">
      <span style="color:#a9a9a9; font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-transform: uppercase;">Online:</span>
      <span style="color:#a9a9a9; font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif; font-size:17px; text-transform: uppercase;"><b>20</b></span>
    </div>

    <div class="goncalo">
      Goncalo
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="imagens/logo.png">
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      Oi
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```